# TreeNodeCollection Control Property C#

Tags: c#, controls, properties

Unfortunately I'm very new to different control properties and was wondering why the following code doesn't work when I try to set the TreeNodeCollection. Is there another way I would be able to obtain a continuous layered "list"?

```
public TreeNodeCollection MenuItems { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MenuItems is already instantiated, just use this

```
MenuItems.AddRange(yourList);
```

Comment: It's a custom control. MenuItems is one of the control's 'properties' which I'd like to be able to edit... But set doesn't seem to work. AddRange isn't quite what I'm looking for but thanks!